# Combining looping and conditional to make new columns on dataframe

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop

I want to make a function with loop and conditional, that count only when Actual Result = 1.
So the numbers always increase by 1 if the Actual Result = 1.

This is my dataframe:

[image]

This is my code but it doesnt produce the result that i want :

```
def func_count(x):
for i in range(1,880):
    if x['Actual Result']==1:
        result = i
    else:
        result = '-'
    return result

X_machine_learning['Count'] = X_machine_learning.apply(lambda x:func_count(x),axis=1)
```

When i check & filter with count != '-' The result will be like this :

[image]

The number always equal to 1 and not increase by 1 everytime the actual result = 1. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'age': [30,25,40,12,16,17,14,50,22,10],
    'actual_result': [0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0]
})

count = 0
lst_count = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['actual_result'][i] == 1:
        count+=1
        lst_count.append(count)
    else:
        lst_count.append('-')

df['count'] = lst_count
print(df)
```

**Result**

```
   age  actual_result count
0   30              0     -
1   25              1     1
2   40              1     2
3   12              1     3
4   16              0     -
5   17              0     -
6   14              1     4
7   50              1     5
8   22              1     6
9   10              0     -
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot it works, thank you for reminding me that a simple list and append can also work. Maybe for others that have same problem with me and get error message KeyError:0 with the code above you can change the code if df['actual_result'][i] == 1 with if df['actual_result'].iloc[i] == 1

Comment: Glad it helped! Please mark this answer as correct, so others know your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to loop over the dataframe, which is mostly a Pandas-antipattern that should be avoided. With `df` your dataframe you could try the following instead:

```py
m = df["Actual Result"] == 1
df["Count"] = m.cumsum().where(m, "-")
```

Result for the following dataframe

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Actual Result": [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]})
```

is

```
   Actual Result Count
0              1     1
1              1     2
2              0     -
3              1     3
4              1     4
5              1     5
6              0     -
7              0     -
8              1     6
9              0     -
```